# how to change the color of navigation toolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I am trying to change the color of the navigation toolbar to black. However the code I am using to try and do this is not working, for some reason I am unsure of.

This is the code that I am using,

```
[self.navigationController.toolbar barStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
```

I have read in the apple's documents on how to use barStyle.. and the values are UIBarStyledefault and Black..

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about this bt try this:

Try this in your viewDidLoad method, or any method in your viewController:

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];

[bar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Have a look at this also

http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesdkdevelopment/browse_thread/thread/4df6af5c0c7f4caf

Comment: Its not the navigation bar its the navigations toolbar